# Adding RESTful capabilities in existing .asmx (SOAP based) webServices

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asmx

I am having an Existing ASMX webservice in Production. I need to add RESTFul capabilities to the same for Rest Clients.

As per my understanding it must be as simple as adding a HTTPHandler (restversion.ashx) implementing IHTTPHandler and calling Business methods while serializing the return objects to XML or byte Stream. Which will be received and interpreted by REST Clients.

Though, while searching on the similar topics, it is not recommended and Can't be done.

Please suggest me..

Comment: Easiest solution: convert it to a WCF service, which offers REST and SOAP out of the box, just a question of configuration...

Comment: I honor your suggestion Marc but Is there any particular reason why the approach I mentioned wouldn't work for me?

Comment: I just think messing around with HTTP handlers and "bolting on" REST capabilities to an already "dead" / legacy technology like ASMX isn't worth the effort....

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP). There are several [tutorials at the end of this page](http://wcf.codeplex.com/). As you can see it is pretty easy to build simple RESTful service. There is also built in test client so you can test your REST service using your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to continue your investment in the legacy ASMX technology, you can create a new WCF REST service, and have it call the existing ASMX service as a client, in order to perform its functions.